# Assert Element is present or not present

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

i got a function which looks something like this :

```
def resultCheck(self, message):
    if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(message)):
        return True
    else: return False
```

And i'd like to assert that the element either exists or doesn't

```
self.assertFalse(self.resultCheck('Something'), 'Detailed search failed!')
```

The problem is that whenever i assertFalse it throws me element not found exception, how can i tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch `NoSuchElementException` to check if an element is visible:

```
def assertVisible(self, message):
    try:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(message)):  
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return False
```